# Export to Excel code doesn't trigger download

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm try to use the following ASP.NET MVC 4 code  to export a table (generated by jTable jquery plugin but it is just a table so that is irrelevant). It does not trigger a download file dialog box.

The other issue is though HTML encoded table is sent by the .ajax() POST, an error is trigger when when I try to process the value with `string inp = Request["input"];` . I have used the `[ValidateInput(false)]` declaration both before & after the [HttpPost] to overcome the "a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client" error (as I'm sending a HTML table) but that declaration doesn't prevent a "a potentially dangerous request.form value..." exception from being thrown -

code in my .cshtml page

```
 $("#exportToExcel").on("click", function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Reports/Export',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { input: $(".jtable").html() },
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    complete: function () {

                    }
                });
            })
```

code in Reports controller:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public void Export()
{
    //string inp = Request["input"];
    string body = "<table><tr><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><table>";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=data.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";

    Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
    Response.Write("<head>");
    Response.Write("<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">");
    Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>");
    Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
    Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
    Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
    Response.Write("<x:Name>Report Data</x:Name>");
    Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
    Response.Write("<x:Print>");
    Response.Write("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>");
    Response.Write("</x:Print>");
    Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
    Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
    Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
    Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
    Response.Write("</xml>");
    Response.Write("<![endif]--> ");
    Response.Write("<![endif]--> ");
    Response.Write("</head>");
    Response.Write("<body>");
    Response.Write(body);
    //Response.Write(inp);
    Response.Write("</body>");
    Response.Write("</html>");
    Response.End();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File download response cannot be achieved from ajax call, there are few methods to achieve this. Following is one of them,

```
$("#exportToExcel").on("click", function (e) {
    var form = $('form');
    var input = $('<input type="hidden" name="input" value="" />');
    input.val($(".jtable").html());
    form.append(input);
    form.attr('action', '/Reports/Export');
    form.attr('method', 'POST');
    form.submit();
})
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @shakib. this info will be useful to me. my main issue though is to trigger the download. the Controller Export method code doesn't work even with a dummy table. once i get that working i can use your code to send real table content.

Comment: The mentioned code will trigger the download. now you just have to make the `Export` action work with correct data. P.S in this method you will find the input either in action parameter `public void Export(string input)` or in formcollection `public void Export(FormCollection data){  var input = data["input"]; }`

Comment: if I have multiple forms, how can I target just this dynamic form from which I'm POST-ing the value

Comment: did not understand what you are trying to say, but the form which is being posted do not exist in the DOM structure, its merely for posting the one input field that holds the jtable values.

Comment: i have 2 forms in the web page. When I look at the HTTP Response Body though IE Dev Tools (Network option 2nd tab Response Body in Detailed View) i see not just "input=%3Cthead....." but a string from the previous form before it.